# What should I do get rid of someone I was in haram relationship with who is blackmailing me now

Tags: halal-haram, sin, dua, forgiveness, fatwa

Assalamualaikum I had been in a haram relationship one year before with a non muslim guy at my college and we were involved in physical activities also (not zina,touching kissing only)but now i have realised that i had been doing sin so I want to get out of this thing as soon as possible I had told the guy many times that we can't stay in a relationship it's haram but he is denying and saying to enjoy life n all .as he is non muslim he is non understanding the fact of haram and halal.i had tried my best but now he is being abusive to me and I am scared that he will tell my parents about our relationship or show pics to them .my parents are very conservative I don't know how they will react to it.please suggest me any dua wazifa or guidance to get rid of this person.i don't love him anymore and I don't want to be with him at all .but I am very helpless I had tried my best to make him understand but he isn't understanding it.please help me as soon as possible.jazakallah.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Please don't confound us with a typical internet forum we don't offer counseling nor peer support. As these kinds of questions are rather subjective. Please consider checking our [help] especially [ask] section and take our [tour] for further information on our site and model. Blackmail is in worst case a matter for the authorities.

Answer (score 1):

He **won't** understand your needs as he puts his first totally before yours. It is pointless in explaining anything to him, because likely, he **won't** listen.

What you can do is be repulsive, vulgar and unattractive, be overly talkative and boring. Be unladylike and disgusting in all manners, dress, behaviour, etc. Behave like a different person that you yourself hate to become.

Cultivate bad manners like burping into your guy's face. Act entitled and be selfish.  Don't be that Miss Nice Girl who says "please" and "thank you." Here, you want to be as repulsive and vulgar as possible, turning him off and seeing  him run in opposite direction. Do whatever he detests.

Next time when you meet him, moan how cold or hot the weather is, be whiny about it. Keep moaning and groaning all the time in his presence. Start complaining about every smallest thing in life and keep arguing about it too long, so much so he detests being with you.
Be a whiner, complainer and pessimist all the time in his presence.
Whatever he talks about, disagree with him. If he dislikes one controversial politician, praise that politician. If he hates Trump, wear a MAGA hat.

Hopefully, he will lose interest in you and find another lady to replace you.

Answer (score 1):

Salaam Alikum, since he had photos, he will try and exploit anytime.
Best thing, Allah knows your intentions are sincere, divulge it to your parents and go to authorities.
May Allah SubhanhuwaTaala grant you help with this taubat an naseeha!
Truth never hurts, always helps over success!

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you should report ti the authorities while asking them to not get your parents involved. They should be able to understand

Comment: Name 10 things that put you off women. Asker above might learn them from you.